# Is it safe to run apache as my user on Mac

Tags: macos, permissions, apache-http-server

I am currently switching from `MAMP` to brew-installed `Apache-Mysql-PHP` environment, and the transition seems well except for the permission setting.

As my scripts need access and change permission of local files, while my folders are set with `755`, files are set with `644` permission, so the default group `daemon` has no permission of changing the files.

I know that I can change the `user` that `httpd` process is running with in `httpd.conf`, but is it safe to change the group to the user I am running with: group `admin`? Or is their a better practice of doing this?

I've read this: https://serverfault.com/questions/346310/running-apache-with-admin-permissions-dangerous, and it says it is possibly safe in my own machine, though I still get some questions:

1. Will it be safer if I change the permission of the folders to `daemon`? In this case, will my user with group `admin` have the modify access to the folder or files: group permission override?
2. If I set the httpd the same permission as the user I am running with, will it still be possible that the PHP in the `www` directory have the access to, or mistakenly change, my files after I set the `php_admin_value open_basedir` in the configuration file?

Comment: is it for lab or dev ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 for dev. and what do you mean by for lab?

Comment: by lab I just mean if it's to test out the config, not in production, as by default namp stack come not secured to be easy to dev on it.

Comment: @yagmoth555 then it's for my dev. and the local environment (version i mean) is not the same as the online ones. So, it's on my personal RMBP, for development usage.

Comment: I now remained the default setting of this permission, and encountered several permission errors. Thinking to change for a while to see what happens.